# error with make apps of hue

Tags: python, hadoop, bigdata, hue

i try to execute "make apps" for Hue, it shows the following error:

> Creating virtual environment at /usr/local/hue/hue/build/env python2.7
>   /usr/local/hue/hue/tools/virtual-bootstrap/virtual-bootstrap.py \ -qq
>   --no-site-packages /usr/local/hue/hue/build/env Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/usr/local/hue/hue/tools/virtual-bootstrap/virtual-bootstrap.py",
>   line 1504, in  main() 
>   File "/usr/local/hue/hue/tools/virtual-bootstrap/virtual-bootstrap.py",
>   line 547, in main use_distribute=options.use_distribute), File
>   "/usr/local/hue/hue/tools/virtual-bootstrap/virtual-bootstrap.py",
>   line 637, in create_environment install_setuptools(py_executable,
>   unzip=unzip_setuptools) File
>   "/usr/local/hue/hue/tools/virtual-bootstrap/virtual-bootstrap.py",
>   line 379, in install_setuptools _install_req(py_executable, unzip)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/hue/hue/tools/virtual-bootstrap/virtual-bootstrap.py",
>   line 355, in _install_req cwd=cwd) File
>   "/usr/local/hue/hue/tools/virtual-bootstrap/virtual-bootstrap.py",
>   line 608, in call_subprocess % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode)) OSError:
>   Command /usr/local/hue/hue/build/env/b...on2.7 -c "#!python
>   \"\"\"Bootstrap setuptoo... " /usr/local/hue/hue/tools/virtu...7.egg
>   failed with error code 1 
>   make: *** [/usr/local/hue/hue/build/env/stamp] Error 1

how can i fixe the problem ?
thanks.

Comment: You have provided way too little information. What is the code you are trying to compile? What are you trying to do? You need to provide more information.

Comment: I want to install Hue on my ubuntu 14. I installed all Pre-Requisite Stuff. when I try to execute 'sudo make apps' in the Hue directory, it shows the above error, Thanks @theAlse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you building Hue on Ubuntu 14.04?

It looks very similar to this packaging bug on Ubuntu: https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!searchin/hue-user/Issue$20with$20Hue$20on$20Ubuntu$2014.04/hue-user/L9Y8X0V6Rww/QXESoj4RRZkJ

Apply https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-1369